# Problema ao ler arquivo .xlsx muito grande em Java

Tags: java

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação web utilizando Java, onde tenho um método que deve ler um arquivo **.xlsx**, usando o **apache-poi**:

```
public static void xlsx(String arquivo) throws IOException{

     try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(arquivo));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell celula = cellIterator.next();
                /*aqui faço a leitura de cada
                celula, fazendo o tratamento adequado 
                a cada campo.
                */
            }
        }
        file.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException("Erro ao processar arquivo.",e.getCause());
    }
}
```

O método funciona corretamente, porem como provavelmente este método irá processar arquivos com milhares de linhas de registros, por exemplo, cerca de 25 a 300 mil linhas. Ao processar um arquivo muito grande eu tomo a seguinte exception:

```
(http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) Servlet.service() for servlet RestServlet threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Queria saber como posso evitar esse tipo de erro. Se tem como por exemplo, ler  e processar o arquivo .xlsx de 1000 em 1000 linhas, ou alguma outra solução.

Comment: Qual a memória que a JVM está usando? Tente aumentar :

`java -Xmx6g seuprograma` (isso chama a JVM com 6 Gigabytes de heap)

Comment: @Kyllopardiun cara, obrigado pela ajuda e acredito que o que me indicou tenha funcionado, configurei a JVM como indicou, porem minha maquina de dev tem apenas 4gb de ram. Acredito que memória não vai ser o problema quando o modulo for para produção, porem não consigo testar e garantir. Você sabe se é possível ler o arquivo em blocos? Por exemplo ir lendo de mil em mil linhas? Se tiver alguma referencia, agradeço.

Comment: Ler arquivos de blocos em blocos existe sim, é um "arquivo mapeado em memória" (Memory Mapped File), sugiro que pesquise sobre isto, aqui por exemplo: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/memorymapped-file-and-io-in-java.html, você também irá precisar de uma implementação para ler estes blocos (talvez quebrá-los em grupos de tags resolva se for um array único)

Comment: Obrigado LeornardoBosquett. Vou pesquisar a referencia que me enviou. Valeu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 Ler o arquivo completo:**

Aumente a heap size do JVM:

```
java Xmx80m seuprograma //80 megabytes (só para mostrar a sintaxe)
java -Xmx6g seuprograma // 6 gigabytes
```

*Note que o JVM é limitado a aproximadamente 2GB em computadores com arquitetura de 32bits*

**2 Entrada Larga e leitura parcial**

Para tratar de uma entrada larga e com pouca memória a melhor opção que conheço é o [apache SXSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf).

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(-1); // cancela o "flushing" automatico e leitura do arquivo completo
// Depois faça o controle manual:
if(rownum % NOR == 0) {
((SXSSFSheet)sh).flushRows(NOR); // mantém NOR linhas e "descarta" o restante
//...
```

Para mais detalhes sugiro que veja e entenda o exemplo no [link](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) postado acima.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, vou fazer o teste com essa implementação com o SXSSF.

Comment: sabe me dizer como posso fazer isso, também com arquivos csv?

Comment: @EricoSouza Essa resposta resolveu o seu problema? Até onde sei o SXSSFWorkbook foi projetado para escrita via streaming e não para leitura via streaming. O próprio link fornecido na resposta apenas fala sobre a escrita.