# Excel com mais de 300 mil linhas

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, apache-poi

Boa noite, estou com um problema com o Excel.

A planilha tem mais de 300 mil linhas e quando rodo o aplicativo com 30 mil linhas não tenho nenhum problema.

O erro só acontece com arquivos que tem muitas linhas.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Estou usando o POI e pesquisando encontrei sobre SXSSF, mas não consegui reproduzir abrindo uma planilha.

```
package br.com.felipebrandao.prjExcel.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.ConvertAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import br.com.felipebrandao.prjExcel.jdbc.ConnectionFactory;

public class LendoColunasNumLoopPorLinhas {
    private String path;
    private static Connection connection;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
        System.out.println("Conexão aberta!");

        Integer linha = 0;
        try {
            File fi = new File("E:\\Projeto\\20102016.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
            XSSFSheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            for (Row rowFor : s) {
                if (rowFor.getRowNum() != 0) {
                    //String sql = "insert into lancamentos (companyCode, account, assignment, documentHeaderText, documentDate, postingDate) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    //PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    System.out.println(rowFor.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());//companyCode
                    System.out.println(rowFor.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());//account
                    System.out.println(rowFor.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());//assignment
                    System.out.println(rowFor.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());//documentHeaderText
                    System.out.println(rowFor.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());//documentDate -date
                    System.out.println(rowFor.getCell(5).getStringCellValue());//postingDate -date
                    //stmt.execute();
                    //stmt.close();
                    linha++;
                    System.out.println(linha);
                }
            }
            wb.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(linha);
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você testou a solução da outra pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27272/28595

Comment: Olá, Felipe. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! O POI utiliza muita memória porque carrega praticamente todo o arquivo em memória. Como mencionado na outra questão linkada, talvez um aumento na memória disponível para a JVM resolva o problema. Você também precisa verificar se seu programa mantém objetos na memória desnecessariamente. Caso não saiba analisar isto, poste o código completo na sua pergunta e poderei ajudar. Explique também em qual contexto esse código executa, se é um programa isolado ou uma aplicação que faz mais coisas, pois neste caso talvez precisa mudar a solução. Abraço!

Comment: Luiz, coloquei todo código, minha ideia é importar essa planilha para um banco de dados, fazer o tratamento dos valores que vem da mesma e passar para o banco.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problema ao ler arquivo .xlsx muito grande em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27259/problema-ao-ler-arquivo-xlsx-muito-grande-em-java)

Comment: Eu acho que o problema está mesmo na forma como está a utilizar o Excel. Convém não esquecer que o Excel não foi idealizado para ser um banco de dados e para ter tanta informação. Existem muitos bancos de dados, incluindo o Access, que permitem trabalhar com 300 mil registos sem pestanejar.